# Prices Zero on listing pages after update to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, upgrade, product-listing

After the upgrade from M1.8.1 to M1.9.3.8 all product prices on the category list pages an the crossselling elements where shown as 0 (Zero) with a strikethrough regular price.

On the detail page everything is fine and shown properly.

The value from getFinalPrice() is "0". We have no catalog rules applied and the product's Special Price fields are all empty (no zeros).

I already deleted the cache and reindexed everything without success.

I have to note, that we actually only have configurable products in the shop and we use multiple store views (to provide different languages). But i already checked for wrong store view overrides without success.

The same issue comes up a lot during my search, but most of the time its vice versa, Listing page is correct and Detail page is wrong. So can't find any solution yet.

UPDATE:

- The issue is related to configurable products only!
- The $product->getData('final_price') function returns zero, whereas the basePrice is correct.
- In a blank Magento 1.9.3.9 installation on the same server everything is ok.
- All modules have been updated to their latest versions. The issue still exists.